# How to chmod in Nautilus via keyboard?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, nautilus, chmod

I like to use the mouse as little as possible, but I find Nautilus useful enough to use it when browsing for files.  If I want to rename a file while in Nautilus I can hit the F2 key; is there a way I can chmod, too?  I really hate going to properties and then permissions and then hitting the combo boxes one by one....

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`nautilus-actions` package can do this.  In the latest unstable release it supports assigning a keybinding to an action.  Even without the keybinding, it saves a few clicks by having an action at the top level of the context menu.